# Azure ADF Error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-data-factory

I'm working with azure ADF and I'm having problems when I execute this query on azure ADF:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
FROM TABLE 
WHERE CONVERT(date, (FORMAT(DATEADD(second, CONVERT(bigint, TS) / 1000, '19700101'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
```

The output is an error

> Arithmetic overflow

but if I change the `=` to a `>=`, the query works and returns an output.

The `TS` is a `UNIXTIMESTAMP` like `1637680012264`.

Using the combination of `>=` and `<` is not ok because I'm dealing with not contiguous days (I need to use `WHERE TS IN (date1, date2, etc...)`

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: `dateadd` already returns a `datetime`, why do you use `FORMAT` only to recast to `date`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger because i need the date in 'yyyy-MM-dd', i don't need the time

Comment: So just `CONVERT(date, ...` ... `FORMAT()` is by far [_the worst possible way to do this_](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

Comment: @SalvatoreBonanno so? Just cast the result of `dateadd` to a date.

Comment: @HoneyBadger just tried it, same error

Comment: If you want to get rows that have today's date, don't convert the column at all, use proper date boundaries with `>=` and `<`. In Pseudo SQL `WHERE YourDateTimeColumn >= {Today's Date} AND YourDateTimeColumn < {Tomorrow's date}`. Getting today and tomorrow's date from the inbuilt functions is quite simple.

Comment: @AaronBertrand so i should do TS/60000 ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand for example i have 1637643918860, 1637643912869, 1637643897921

Comment: @AaronBertrand there are milliseconds too in this Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Preferably, I would change the table to store `datetime2` values instead of convoluted epoch junk.

But, assuming you can't fix the design...

To Larnu's point, you don't want to apply computations to the column,  and you definitely don't want to apply `FORMAT()` to both sides because [`FORMAT()` is an absolute dog](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

Instead, I would find the boundaries for today, and use an open-ended range. This assumes the `TS` column must be `bigint`:

```
DECLARE @d date = GETDATE();

DECLARE @start bigint = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', @d),
        @end   bigint = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', DATEADD(DAY, 1, @d));

SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
FROM dbo.[TABLE]
WHERE TS >= @start * 1000 
  AND TS <  @end   * 1000;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d6cbbaf97cadb9a866197c7a4d1db2e)

This avoids any formatting overhead, convoluted and unnecessary convert expressions (`TS` must already be a `bigint`, right, so why the explicit `CONVERT()`?).

---

If you need non-contiguous dates, ok, we can still accomplish this with far less abuse of the table. Just create a #temp table or table variable with computed columns, insert your multiple dates in there, and then outer join to it.

```
DECLARE @d table
(
  d datetime2, 
  s AS CONVERT(bigint, 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', d)) * 1000,
  e AS CONVERT(bigint, 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', DATEADD(DAY, 1, d))) * 1000
);

INSERT @d(d) VALUES('20211123'),('20211007');

-- if you want a row per day:
SELECT d.d, COUNT(t.TS) AS c
FROM @d AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[TABLE] AS t
   ON  t.TS >= d.s
   AND t.TS <  d.e
GROUP BY d.d
ORDER BY d.d;

-- if you just want a total count:
SELECT COUNT(t.TS) AS c
FROM @d AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[TABLE] AS t
   ON  t.TS >= d.s
   AND t.TS <  d.e;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6225740fd6591241a8fdeac1e2108a52)

---

Lots more on date bad habits & best practices:

- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, even though your solution it isn't what i was looking for you illuminated my team with "That's not the source of the error. DATEADD is never going to be able to add 3 billions seconds to 1970. So maybe divide again and try adding by minutes, if you only care about the date, second-level accuracy shouldn't be important. Can you provide a couple of sample values for TS and expected results for those".
So converted the UNIXTIMESTAMP in DAYS by divinding for 60*60*1000*24

Comment: @SalvatoreBonanno But that's still an extremely inefficient way to solve the problem. You want the math on the other side of the where clause, trust me. Unless the `TS` column is not indexed and you know for a fact you will never index it.

Comment: Yep, i saw the solution with the temp table. The most problematic stuff is that i can only have read access to the table ( the table is on the cloud) so i don't  know nothing about index on it (it could be a view too!) . So the math problem solved the issue for now, but i'll try to optimized it as you said up.